# Cookie can be create and access from Postman, but not from client side

Tags: .net, cookies

I have two API calls which one is for create a cookie and other is for read the cookie. It **does work** when I am calling the APIs from **Postman**, but from my **angular client side**, it doesn't **work**.

Here's the cookie I am creating:

```
currentContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my_Test_Cookie", "2342", new CookieOptions()
{
    HttpOnly = false,
    Domain = ".localhost",
    Path = "/",
    MaxAge = new TimeSpan(10, 10, 10),
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = true              
});
```

Here is the cookie access part:

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["my_Test_Cookie"];
```